# Login module control flag is not available in the JAAS config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, oauth-2.0

I had a next configuration for KafkaAdminClient:

```
client-config {
  bootstrap.servers = ${bootstrap.servers}
  schema.registry.url = ${schema.registry.url}
  security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=“url”
  sasl.mechanism="OAUTHBEARER"
  sasl.login.callback.handler.class="org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler"
  sasl.jaas.config = "file:absolute/path/to/file”
}
```

Configuration file for jaas (we use OAuth 2.0 for authorization):

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
    oauth.client.id="uid"
    oauth.client.secret="secret"
    oauth.scope="scope";
};
```

However I got an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Login module control flag is not available in the JAAS config
```

What is reason of this and how can I fix it?